# Storyboard Error after Upgrading to Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard, xcode12

Since I switched to Xcode 12 I have problems with my storyboard. When I open the storyboard file if shows the following error:

**The document “Main.storyboard” had 97 issues that were found and repaired.**
This may be due to an SCM operation such as merging. Please save the document to fix the issues.

[image: error screenshot]

I opened the file as source code and found indeed a lot of duplicates inside the `<resources>` tag. Those duplicates look like this:

```
<systemColor name="darkTextColor">
<color white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/> 
</systemColor>
```

I started removing those duplicates, so that only one entry is left. Then I opened the file again in Interface Builder. Now I does not show the error mentioned above but it still says: "*An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited.*"

Now if I close the file and open it again, Xcode is automatically adding the duplicates mentioned above again and the error "*The document “Main.storyboard” had 97 issues that were found and repaired.*" is displayed again.

This procedure repeats again and again if I continue removing the duplicates...

**UPDATE**

I reached out to Apple Developer Technical Support and got the advice to replace all occurrences of `groupTableViewBackgroundColor` with `systemGroupedBackgroundColor`.

I have done this and now the error mentioned above does not show up anymore but editing functionalities is still limited in my storyboard and I see those blue boxes around my view controllers. I hope a future Xcode version will fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue regarding the "An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited." message in Xcode and found that it was related to the `UISplitViewController` im my storyboard. If your storyboard uses a `UISplitViewController`, select it in Xcode and verify the value of the "Style" property in the Attributes Inspector. For me it was set to "Unspecified (Discouraged)". After I changed it to "Double Column", saved the storyboard, closed the storyboard (you may just want to close the whole Xcode project) and opened the storyboard/project again, everything worked fine.

(And thanks for your update regarding replacing `groupTableViewBackgroundColor` with `systemGroupedBackgroundColor` – I had to do this too.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem. Probably is an Xcode issue, it will be resolved in the next version. Anyway, it is annoying, but it hasn't any effect.

Update: it seems that the problem only affects two kind of attributes: darkTextColor and GroupTableColour (Secondary, Tertiary...).
Changing them with other attributes (like "Default label colour") solves the problem. Wierd!

EDITED:
Solved with Xcode 12.3

Comment: I also have the same problem as you but with viewFlipsideBackgroundColor

Comment: I have the same problem. I was able to find a couple instances of lightTextColor being called out by ViewController layouts.  This reduced the number of issues. I wasn't able to find where groupTableViewBackgound color was called after reviewing all TableViews. I still have 15 issues (colors).  In my case, xcode crashes often when going in and out of storyboard graphics and usually takes at least 3 or 4 restarts to load the app again. Very annoying! Any help in finding the colors or avoiding the crashes would be helpful.